# Modifying constraints in child controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, constraints

I have a `TabBarController` that is connected to one view controller which is of class `class MainViewController: UIViewController`

[image: Storyboard]

`MainViewController` has the following constraint as a property:

`@IBOutlet weak var ContainerBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!`

and the following method to modify the constraint:

```
func resizeContainer() {
    ContainerBottomConstraint.constant = Constants.playingNowBarHeight
}
```

I want to call `resizeContainer()` from the `TabBarController` Right now I'm trying to call it from `viewDidLoad()` like this

```
if let vc = viewControllers?[0] as? MainViewController {
        vc.resizeContainer()
}
```

However I'm getting 
`Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` 
on the line `ContainerBottomConstraint.constant = Constants.playingNowBarHeight`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding a property to `MainViewController` and updating it in `TabBarController` then updating the constraints depending on the value of the property in `viewDidLoad` in `MainViewController`.

In `MainViewController`

```
var shouldResize: Bool = false

private func initView(){
   if shouldResize {
        ContainerBottomConstraint.constant = Constants.playingNowBarHeight
    } else {
        ContainerBottomConstraint.constant = 0
    }
}
```

In `TabBarController`

```
if let vc = viewControllers?[0] as? MainViewController {
    vc.shouldResize = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBOutlet lazy var containerBottomConstraint = containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: someView.topAnchor)
```

If you declare a constraint as an instance property of a view controller, you need to make that `var` `lazy` *and* you must initialize it. A lazy variable is only read when it's used.

Then in the view controller, activate it:

```
containerBottomConstraint.isActive = true
```

And now that constraint is an instance property.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `Lazy properties must have an initializer`